# onPageReference doesn't work

Tags: lightning-aura-components, pagereference, lightningnavigation

I have a custom lwc that navigates to an aura and it's working fine but whenever I change the url parameters the onPageReference method from the aura is not working.

This is my lwc code:

```
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({ 
            type : 'standard__component' ,
            attributes : {
                componentName : 'c__MyAuraComponent'
            },
            state : {
                c__previousPageReference : //previous page reference,                    
                c__question : //object,
                c__questionId : //id
            }
        });
```

And this is my aura:

cmp:

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.onPageReferenceChange}"/>
```

controller.js:

```
onPageReferenceChange: function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('**reference has changed');
    helper.managePageReference(component);
},
```

But I'm not being able to get the console log.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Regards,

**EDIT**
My aura also has a onInit handler and both onInit and onPageReferenceChange call the same helper method for data retrieve based on url:

cmp:

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.onPageReferenceChange}"/>
```

controller.js:
onPageReferenceChange: function(component, event, helper) {
console.log('**reference has changed', component.get("v.pageReference"));
helper.managePageReference(component);
},
doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
helper.managePageReference(component);
},

helper.js:

```
managePageReference: function (component, event) {
    var myPageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");
    if(myPageRef && myPageRef.state){
        Object.keys(myPageRef.state).forEach(key => {
            let fixedKey = key.split('c__').pop();
            component.set("v." + fixedKey, myPageRef.state[key]);
        });
    }
},
```

Comment: How do these two components interact? You've said that the LWC navigates to the aura component, but are you expecting the LWC to update the Aura component on navigation if that Aura component exists? Sorry, but I'm struggling to understand what you're meaning with your question.

Comment: Hi @CallumMacErlich. My lwc display a number of items and each item can navigate to the same aura but with different data that's been updated to the componente. Whenever I go back to the lwc and try picking a different item the onPageReference method doesn't launch.

Comment: Have you got an onInit method in your aura component? My understanding is that each time you navigate to the Aura component it would be a new instance of it, rather than the same one.

Comment: @CallumMacErlich Yes, I have an onInit handler and the onchange handler attached to the pageReference. onInit is working fine but onPageReference is not. I'll update the question

Comment: @CallumMacErlich question edited for better context. Also thanks for your help and quick response!

Comment: No worries at all! You have me intrigued now. Does that onInit method get called each time you navigate to the aura, or is it actually only the first time?

Comment: @CallumMacErlich Only the first time. That's what's making me worry about this...

Comment: Does setting the navigation to override history event do anything? this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({ 
            type : 'standard__component' ,
            attributes : {
                componentName : 'c__MyAuraComponent'
            },
            state : {
                c__previousPageReference : //previous page reference,                    
                c__question : //object,
                c__questionId : //id
            }
        },true);

Comment: Thanks @CallumMacErlich! Now it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just summarizing the solution if this impacts anyone else.

The simple fix for this is to update the call to the Navigate API to pass the 'replace' argument. This means that the page state is updated without pushing a new history entry onto the browser's history stack.

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](PageReference, true);
```

This is loosely detailed in the '[Add Query Parameters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_add_params_url)' LWC Developer Guide documentation.